# gradle 2.6 play plugin: How to add play local dependency

Tags: gradle, playframework, build, sbt

I check the tutorial (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/play_plugin.html) The typical way of adding a dependency in gradle play plugin is :

```
dependencies {
    play "commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6"
}
```

My question is how to add play's dependency like 'cache'. I know in build.sbt it should looks like:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.22",

)
```

In sbt, we can directly refer to 'cache'. but in gradle play plugin, I tried directly refer to it like :

```
dependencies {
    play "cache"
}
```

but this doesn't work.

So how should I declare these dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Cache is defined in play sbt plugin. You can find its value using the consoleProject command from an sbt console.

```
root> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info]
import sbt._
import Keys._
import dsl._
import _root_.play.sbt.Play.autoImport._
import _root_.play.sbt.routes.RoutesCompiler.autoImport._
import _root_.play.twirl.sbt.SbtTwirl.autoImport._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_31).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> cache
res0: sbt.ModuleID = com.typesafe.play:play-cache:2.4.2

scala> javaJdbc
res1: sbt.ModuleID = com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc:2.4.2
```